# binding part of XML as dataSource

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an **XML** like one below and a list in **С#** project which have to be binded to this XML partly according to child name using Data Name as DisplayMember and Data val as ValueMember.

My question is: How can I, using **LINQ**, find the specific node by it's attribute and use its children as Data source?

E.g. if a user wants to see **transaction_type**, list must be binded to only the first **child** node

```
<Root>
  <Child Name="transaction_type">
    <Data val="1" Name="authorization"/>
    <Data val="2" Name="confirm"/>
    <Data val="3" Name="purchase"/>
  </Child>
  <Child Name= "transaction_status">
    <Data val="1" Name ="initiated"/>
    <Data val="2" Name ="external processing"/>
  </Child>
  <Child Name ="country_by_bin">
    <Data val="AF" Name="Afghanistan"/>
    <Data val="AX" Name="Aland Islands"/>
    <Data val="AL" Name="Albania"/>
    <Data val="DZ" Name="Algeria"/>
    <Data val="AS" Name="American Samoa"/>
  </Child>
```

Comment: does your xml contains namespace? like `<document xmlns='http://www.abcd.com/dxl' version='9.0' someversion='1.0' `

Comment: it seems your xml is not in proper format, second <child> node not closed and <Root> node also not closed. Please share your proper xml so it will help us to give you solution

Comment: Yes but just the version and encoding  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: You could desearialize to an object, and select the Data nodes of a certain child, and then bind to that list of objects.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, i cut a bit of the file so it would not take a lot of space here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over `Child` nodes and get specific name child node.

And after that you will get display member and value member list like

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\Files\XMLFile2.xml");

        var childs = doc.Descendants("Child")
                          .Single(c => c.Attribute("Name").Value == "transaction_type")
                          .Elements().ToList();

        var displayMembers = childs.Attributes("Name").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        var valueMembers = childs.Attributes("val").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Alex Shangin, view the answer might be it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a code that performs the conversion of xml to DataSet and even an entity. Try to use this conversion and after that do your LINQ query.

```js
        public static string SerializeObject<T>(T dataObject)
        {
            if (dataObject == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Object is NULL");

            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, dataObject);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
             where T : class
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty XML ERROR");

            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }
        }
```

Entity exemple:

```js
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CLIENTE")]
    public class Client
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ROW")]
        public List<ClientInfo> Row { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ROW")]
    public class ClientInfo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TABELA")]
        public string NomeTabela { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID_CLIENTE", Type = typeof(int))]
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID_CLIENTE_RECADASTRO")]
        public string ClientIDRecadastro { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NOME_CLIENTE")]
        public string NomeCliente { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TIPO_CLIENTE")]
        public string TipoCliente { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime DataRecadastro { get; set; }
```